# 'express' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I was implementing a websocket chat server for my full stack web app and came to realisation that most of the sources out there only provide tutorial for html+js and I'm not exactly sure of how to migrate over from JS to JSX.

I started trying to integrate the js codes into my jsx chat component file but came across with the issue that the `express() is undefined`

Here's my JS to establish the express server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

uses = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
console.log('server running...');
```

Here's my attempt to do it in JSX:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ChatComponent extends Component {

  state = { 
    express: require('express'),
    app: express(),
    server: require('http').createServer(this.app),
    io: require('socket.io').listen(this.server),
    users: [],
    connections: [],
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      ...
```

When I try npm start it, i get this message, but no idea of how to fix it:

```
./src/components/chat/ChatComponent.jsx
  Line 7:  'express' is not defined  no-undef
```

I have also included the express and socket.io dependencies in my package.json and npm update it as well

```
{
  "name": "javlet-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "express": "*",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.5",
    "react-new-window": "^0.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-webcam": "^3.0.1",
    "socket.io": "*",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "uws": "^10.148.1",
    "yarn": "^1.17.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "jest --coverage"
  },
 ...
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
More code can be provided if needed. Thanks

Comment: [express](https://expressjs.com/) is the server side NodeJS library, you are not supposed to use it in React

Comment: I believe JSX is shorthand for React.createElement which finally creates DOM elements. You can't migrate everything JS to JSX

Answer (score 4):

Express is a node server side library, whilst react is a client side library. So for a chat app setup you would create an both an express server, and a react app.

The express server would serve the react app to the browser, and the react app would get the chat data from the express server.

To get something quick running

Inside a project folder, create a server folder, and inside that a file named index.js.
Inside the server folder, from the terminal run:

```
npm init -y
```

followed by:

```
npm i express socket.io
```

That takes care of the server dependencies.
Now inside index.js:

server/index.js:

```
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(4000);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("express-server");
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.emit("news", { message: "Hello World" });
  socket.on("my other event", function(data) {
    console.log("response to my other event: ", data);
  });
});
```

This sets up the server to be available on localhost:4000.
To test this, from the terminal - inside the server folder - run:

```
node index.js
```

Now from the browser go to localhost:4000, and you should see the message express-server.
That's everything done on the backend.

On to the react app.

Iside the project folder, from the terminal run:

```
npx create-react-app client
```

This may take a couple of minutes, but a basic react app will be created in the client folder.

When create-react-app has finished it's time to install the react dependencies, so inside the client folder run:

```
npm i socket.io-client
```

Almost there.

Navigate to client/src/App.js, and replace everything inside with:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    news: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const handleMessage = (message) => {
      this.setState({ news: message })
    }

    const socket = socketIOClient('http://127.0.0.1:4000')
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
      handleMessage(data.message)
      socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>React Socket.io</h1>
          <p>{this.state.news}</p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now if you go to the terminal inside the client folder, and run:

```
npm run start
```

That will start the react app and automatically open the app in your browser.

You should at this point have the react app running in the browser, and the express app also running.

The react app should show:

## React Socket.io

#### Hello World

and the express terminal should show:

```
response to my other event: { my: 'data' }
```

To explain what happened in the react app -

- We imported socket.io-client at the start of the page - in react all dependencies are imported at the start with import statements.
- At the start of the component we setup an empty string for state.news, this stops us from getting an error when the component first mounts, before we have received and data from the server.
- React class components have a number of built-in methods known as lifecycle methods, componentDidMount is one of these, it is a method that is run once as soon as the component is mounted in the browser. This is where we have connected to the express server, so socket.io listens for data from the server, when it receives a message it passes it to the handleMessage function, which calls setState() with the message.
- setState() is a method built into react, it is used to change/add values to the component state.
- Finally due to the way react works, since the state has changed, the component is re-rendered and the 'Hello World' message is displayed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So we're not doing anything with the JSX component?

Comment: Hi, well JSX is the code that React uses to render elements in the browser, it's a mixture of javascript and HTML. 
In the example above, in the App Component, the section that looks like HTML - inside the render function - is written in JSX.
In summary, JSX is a HTML like syntax that is used inside React Components, on the frontend.